# RedShift: Extracting Data from Schema tables

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, schema

Good afternoon/evening/morning (depending on your location).

I have a question in regards to connecting to `RedShift Schema > view >  table` using `Python3.4` and `psycopg2`

I know I am able to connect to tables within a database, but I am having an issue with trying to connect to a schema table.

When I try connecting to the table within a Schema view, I receive FATAL error:

> "table name" does not exist. dbname

I have tried using the `view > name` (which holds the column names and data for that view)

Example coding: 
If I remove the sql query and just try and make a connection, I receive *the same response that the dbname does not exist*:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(user = 'user-name', password = 'password',
host = 'aws-host-link', dbname = 'schema-name', port = 1234)
mycursor = conn.cursor()
sql = mycursor.execute('select * from schema-name')

print(sql)
mycursor.close()
conn.close()
```

The trace back, posts:

> fatal: dbname "schema-name" does not exist.

I have searched through stack exchange, google, and aws. The only thing I was able to find is: Unable to connect to a schema and I need to connect directly to a database.

I am unsure if trying to connect to a schema is possible. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated and a thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you attempting to query a schema? Schemas are groupings of tables -- they can''t be queried. If you wish to query a table in a specific schema, you can use the syntax `select * from schema-name.table-name`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried schema-name.table-name before I posted my question and I received none. When I query mysql view tables, I receive the table information, I assumed I would be able to do the same in Redshift.

Comment: @John
Thank you sir. I figured this out. The issue I was having, I was missing a line of code. (This may have been why I was receiving errors. not sure but since I added the line, I receive schema table info.)
cursor.fetchall()

Comment: Is this question still likely to help other StackOverflow users in future? If so, please add information to help them if they have a similar problem. If not, feel free to delete the question.

Comment: @John, yes. Just add this line after the sql line: mycursor = cursor.fetchall()